# Output javascript value in a text input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not very good in javascript. I have coded this javascript:

```
function calculateTotal()
{
    var cakePrice = 4 + ( 5 + 7 + 9 + 2 ) * ( 8 * 3 );    

    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = cakePrice;
    $('add').val(divobj);
}
```

I am outputting it inside an input field when the page loads:

```
<body onload='calculateTotal()'>
    <input type="text" required="required" name="total" class="text" id="totalPrice"/>
</body>
```

The problem is that the value is not displayed in the input field when the page loads. When I try the same javascript with a div, it works. I want to make the value to be outputted in the input field because the value is still needed for user manipulation. Kindly check and help me on how to do it.

Comment: If you're using jQuery you should add the tag to your question.

Comment: @j08691 I'm not using jQuery

Comment: What's the `$('add')` for? Prototype? Mootools?

Comment: @Juhana I think ASP.NET provides a function like that too - maybe I'm thinking of something else. I'm still confused why they're using "add" and not "totalPrice"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

```
divobj.value = cakePrice;
```

More generally:

```
// the selector is here for caching, so the browser doesn't have to look for it every time
// Make sure you put your code in the bottom of the body section, or inside a ready handler
var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice'); 
function calculateTotal(){

    var cakePrice = 4 + ( 5 + 7 + 9 + 2 ) * ( 8 * 3 );    
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.value = cakePrice;
}
```

#### [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ePXN/)

Comment: Hi @Benjamin Gruenbaum, it worked. Should I leave out the        $('add').val(divobj);

Comment: @user2103187 Yes, you should :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it took me days trying to figure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you already have your element stored in a variable, as well as the value you want to display:

```
divobj.value = cakePrice;
```

Comment: Yes, but in OP's example, no such element exists.

Comment: @Juhana Correct, good comment, assuming it's jQuery. (Which OP just said he isn't using :))

Comment: Edited answer, found out OP wasn't using jQuery, misleading tags! :X

Answer (score -1):

Try do to this:

```
<input type="text" id="totalPrice" />
```

JS:

```
$().ready(function(){
    var total = 4 + ( 5 + 7 + 9 + 2 ) * ( 8 * 3 );
    $('#totalPrice').val(total);
});
```

Comment: Don't use `$().ready(function(){`.  Either do `$(document).ready(function(){` or `$(function(){`.  Docs: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Ok, the docs said this is not recommended, but, it works. I didn't understand why you vote down in my reputation because of this. I understood your answer, but I didn't agree with votedown...

Comment: I assume the downvote is for a jQuery answer for someone who doesn't use jQuery.

Comment: @ViniciusLima: I didn't down-vote, I just wanted to point that out.